# Meaning: "Let's set this party off right"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, lyrics

There is a sentence in *Bruno Mars' 24k magic*

> Let's set this party off right

what does "off right" mean here?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should read the off together with the set. To set off, [according to OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/set-off):

> to start a process or series of events

So it means to start the party. The right is used as an adverb, meaning [according to OLD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/right_2):

> *correctly* or *satisfactorily*